# in VB 6.0 through IdxxStatmentTree.cls -Out of memory issue while inserting new record

Tags: vb6, controls, out-of-memory, reorderlist

```
Private Sub AddToOutline(ol As Object, psModel As String, pnKeyOfNode As Long, pnStmtRef As Long, pnLabCount, psFT As Variant, pnFV As Variant, psFV As Variant, pvStatus As Variant, pbExpand As Boolean)
    Dim sStmt As String  'Stores the VCA Statement node for adding to the outline
    Dim sLabel As String 'Store the VCA Label node for adding to the outline
    
    Dim outidxS As Integer  'outline pointer for the statement
    Dim outidxL As Integer 'outline pointer for the label
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nPos As Integer

    'psModel is optional
    If psModel <> "" Then
        LocateModel ol, psModel
    End If

    'First array element should be a MARQUE label
    If psFT(0) <> FT_MARQUE Then
        MsgBox "WARNING: VCA Statement " & pnStmtRef & " is Missing its Marque VCA Label"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Second Array element must be the MODEL RANGE Label
    If psFT(1) <> FT_MODEL_RANGE Then
        MsgBox "WARNING: VCA Statement " & pnStmtRef & " is Missing its Model Range VCA Label"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------
    '  FIRST:   Add the VCA Statement Node to the Outline
    '----------------------------------------------------------
    
    'Add the VCA Statement Status if provided
    If Not IsNull(pvStatus) Then
        If pvStatus <> "A" Then
            sStmt = sStmt & OL_STMT_UNAVAILABLE & " "
        End If
    End If
    
    'Set the Statement Number
    sStmt = sStmt & pnStmtRef
    
    If pnLabCount = 2 Then
        sStmt = sStmt & " (Whole Model)"
    Else
        'Build up Statement string  (e.g.  "10001 -> T Series + Turbo Charger Fitted")
        sStmt = sStmt & " -> "
        For i = 2 To pnLabCount - 1
            If i > 2 Then sStmt = sStmt & " + "
            sStmt = sStmt & psFV(i)
        Next i
    End If
    
    'Add The VCA Statement Node to the Outline
    ol.AddItem sStmt
    ol.Expand(ol.ListIndex) = pbExpand  'Optionally expand the VCA Statement node
    
    'Re-position to newly added item
    'The picturetype is include in the condition on the loop
    'to cater for the fact that sStmt may not be unique on its own
    outidxS = ol.ListIndex
    Do
        outidxS = outidxS + 1
    Loop Until ol.List(outidxS) = sStmt And ol.PictureType(outidxS) <> 1
    ol.ListIndex = outidxS

    '9/10/97 ol.ItemData(outidxS) = pnStmtRef  'Store Statement ref as the key
    ol.ItemData(outidxS) = pnKeyOfNode  'Store Statement ref as the key
    ol.indent(outidxS) = 2
    ol.PictureType(outidxS) = 1
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------
    '  SECOND:   Add each of the VCA Label Nodes to the Outline
    '----------------------------------------------------------
        
    'Only needed if more than 2 labels, i.e more than just Marque and Model Range labels
    If pnLabCount > 2 Then
    
        For i = 2 To pnLabCount - 1
            
            'Add the VCA Label to the Outline
            sLabel = psFT(i) & " = " & psFV(i)
            ol.AddItem sLabel, ol.ListIndex + 1
            outidxL = ol.ListIndex + 1
            ol.ItemData(outidxL) = pnFV(i)  'Store the VCA_LAB_REF as the key
            ol.indent(outidxL) = 3
            ol.PictureType(outidxL) = 2
            ol.ListIndex = outidxL
        
        Next i
        
    End If 'pnLabCount
    
    'Reset Position in tree
    ol.ListIndex = outidxS
        
End Sub

'Re-position an Outline Control to the supplied Model
'If not found then the Model will be added to the Outline
Public Sub LocateModel(ol As Object, psModel As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'Try and find the same Model in the Outline
    **ol.ListIndex = -1**
    For i = 0 To ol.ListCount - 1
        If ol.indent(i) = 1 Then
            If ol.List(i) = psModel Then
                ol.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        End If '.indent
    Next i
    
    'If Model Not found ...
    If ol.ListIndex = -1 Then
        ol.AddItem psModel
        ol.ListIndex = ol.ListCount - 1
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Did you debug it to see where the out of memory error is occurring?

Comment: Yes Andrew, outidxS = ol.ListIndex thrown error while adding new stmt